# Up-/Downsampling of a logical vector (not with zeros)

Tags: matlab, resampling

I hope you can help with a little problem I am having.
I want to upsample and downsample a vector with zeros and ones. We have the functions upsample and downsample for that, however, the upsample function in Matlab only adds zeros to the vector. I would like to repeat the value, instead of just putting in zeros.

Unfortunately the upsample function does not do that. Thus, I tried to use repmat (in the third dimension) and then reshape to get back to the old format. I know it must be possible with these functions, but if I simply use them, the vector just gets duplicated and added to the end.

An example: 
The input vector is: [1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0] (these should be random).

Now I want to upsample (say) by a factor of 2. Then I want to get: 
[1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0].

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html):

```
>> repelem([1 0 1],2)
ans =
     1     1     0     0     1     1
```

Or using `repmat` and `reshape` when `input` is a column vector:

```
>> input = [1 0 1];
>> reshape(repmat(input, 2, 1), 1, [])
ans =
     1     1     0     0     1     1
```